# How to mount external drive directly under "/media/" and not under "/media/username/"?

Tags: 12.10, mount, drive

I have been facing a new and annoying problem after installing Apache2 on my new 12.10 distribution.

I have done this at least 20 times before with older distributions and had no problems up until now.

The partition on my external drive is named `EXT4`. Until now it was mounted as: `/media/EXT4` and was perfectly functioning when I changed `DocumentRoot` in `sites-available` to read:

```
DocumentRoot /media/EXT4/www
```

In my Ubuntu 12.10 distribution it is mounted as: `/media/USERNAME/EXT4` which seems unreadable by Apache.

I gathered if I somehow force Ubuntu to do as before (mount at `/media/EXT4`) it might work. I've already tried everything else, such as `chmod`, `chgrp` and `chown`.

Manifestation of the problem: `localhost/index.php returns a 403 error`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your `/etc/fstab` file specifying the mount point you wish.

Open a terminal and type `sudo blkid`. Identify the partition and copy its UUID.

Then `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`

Add a line like this:

```
UUID=your-UUID-here /media/EXT4               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

Reboot or run `sudo mount -a` and you're done.